# iPhone 4S chip overheating after replacing screen

Tags: ios, hardware, iphone, temperature

I just bought a used iPhone 4S with cracked screen, and installed a new [lcd with gold frame](http://www.ebay.com/itm/TOUCH-LCD-GOLD-full-assembly-back-cover-home-button-set-iphone-4S-UK-/330921833318?pt=UK_Replacement_Parts_Tools&hash=item4d0c7a7366). Just after putting the phone together it starts overheating. I have not installed any apps since recovery (fresh start). It seems as if the chip and the flash memory gets extremely hot. I almost burned myself touching it! The battery drains quickly from 20% to shutdown in a few minutes.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Are location services on, and being used?

Comment: Just replacing the screen wouldn't cause this... what was the cause of the broken screen in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

This seems relevant: https://www.hcqs.com.cn/blog/how-to-fix-iphone-overheating-after-screen-replacement.  It indicates that while replacing the screen one could introduce a short that causes overheating.